# Updating a kivy label on a screen when dynamically generating it through a list?

Tags: label, kivy

Firstly, disclaimer: I am terribly new to programming and am trying to build my understanding with this project. Additionally, let me say I have searched the forums and found similar posts to mine, but none have the issue of updating a label that has been dynamically generated through a list.

My question is in my code, commented out, but to summarize: I generate buttons and labels for each item in a list. Then the buttons should add and subtract from the linked value in a dictionary. Currently the code does this, but the labels on screen don't update to reflect the new values. Can someone please assist with updating the value for "ordlayout.add_widget(ordlayout.lbl[str(i)])" when calling to updateup and updatedown?

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from functools import partial
#The first screen the app opens to. Contains all other screen branches.
class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

#NewOrder will be the screen used for choosing which
#items/and how many of each the customer wants added.
class NewOrder(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NewOrder, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #This will eventually read/create a list of strings from a user-modified file.
        self.foods = ["Puppy", "Cat", "Fish"]
        #I create a dictionary linking a number to each item.
        self.countfoods = {}
        for i in self.foods:
            self.countfoods[i] = 0
        #Now I create a grid layout to put on the screen.
        ordlayout = GridLayout()
        ordlayout.cols = 8
        ordlayout.row_default_height=20
        ordlayout.buttons={}
        ordlayout.btns1 = {}
        ordlayout.lbl = {}
        #The items I want on the screen are 1.)First item from list. 2.) Minus button.
        #3.) Current number of the item. 4.) Plus button.
        #I want these four buttons for each item.
        for i in self.countfoods:
            #Adds text for first item.
            ordlayout.add_widget(Label(text=i))
            #Adds a button for minus, linked to a unique dict value.
            ordlayout.buttons[str(i)] = Button(text="-")
            ordlayout.lbl[str(i)] = Label(text=str((self.countfoods[i])))
            #The below assigns the specific object location of each label
            #to a variable for passing to ocuntup and countdown.
            tempPlacement = str(ordlayout.lbl[str(i)])
            ordlayout.buttons[str(i)].bind(on_press=partial(self.updatedown, i))
            ordlayout.add_widget(ordlayout.buttons[str(i)])
            #Add the value that I want to update.
            ordlayout.add_widget(ordlayout.lbl[str(i)])
            #Adds a button for addition, but doesn't properly link it to a specific value.
            ordlayout.btns1[str(i)] = Button(text="+")
            ordlayout.btns1[str(i)].bind(on_press=partial(self.updateup, i))
            ordlayout.add_widget(ordlayout.btns1[str(i)])
        #Add that grid wit
            h values to the screen.
        self.add_widget(ordlayout)

    #Function used to change value down by one.
    def updatedown(self, event, i):
        self.countfoods[event] -= 1
        print (self.countfoods)

    #Function used to change value up by one.
    def updateup(self, event, i):
        self.countfoods[event] += 1
        print (self.countfoods)


#AdminOpt will be the screen used for
class AdminOpt(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AdminOpt, self).__init__(**kwargs)

#Will allow for opening and checking of created orders.
class OrdHist(Screen):
    pass

#This is purely the class used for managing the other screens.
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


Main = Builder.load_file("Order Handler2.kv")


class Customer:
    def __init__(self, name, pricelist):
        self.name = name
        self.pricelist = pricelist


class SimpleKivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main


if __name__== "__main__":
    SimpleKivy().run()
```

Comment: Your `updateup` and `updatedown` methods need to explicitly change the `text` property of the `Label` in addition to changing the vale.

Comment: I was aware that the label needed updated, but I'm not sure on how to word the code to do so. I had thought something akin to-

self.ordlayout.lbl[str(event)] += 1

However, this returns something akin to "self has no attribute ordlayout". I will update with the exact error when possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't been able to test this (your question is missing your `kv` file), but something like this might work:

```
#Function used to change value down by one.
def updatedown(self, i, button):
    self.countfoods[i] -= 1
    self.ordlayout.lbl[str(i)].text = str(self.countfoods[i])
    print (self.countfoods)

#Function used to change value up by one.
def updateup(self, i, button):
    self.countfoods[i] += 1
    self.ordlayout.lbl[str(i)].text = str(self.countfoods[i])
    print (self.countfoods)
```

You will also need to replace every occurence of `ordlayout` with `self.ordlayout` in the `__init__()` method.

As an aside, you don't need to do `str(i)` for your dictionary keys. In fact, you can use lists instead of dictionaries, if you prefer.